# Can't run any file in path even if the path is present in `bashrc`

Tags: bash

I am trying to run `conda` which is installed in `/home/ubu/anaconda3/bin`
When I enter this path and run `./conda` it does run, trying to make the file executable whith `sudo chmod +x ./conda`
 showes no message (normal) but still can't execute it through `conda` command.

My `.bashrc` contains `export PATH="/home/ubu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Same goes for `jupyter`, or other tools in `/bin`

Comment: Does `echo "$PATH"` show the correct path?

Comment: `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ubu/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ubu/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` I guess it concatenates mixing paths, you are right!

Comment: I (don't) see a missing colon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @the other guy pointed, I had to check $PATH variable then I found:

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ubu/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ubu/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

The order of exports messed the evaluated paths for the latest. I put the one without a variable ${path} in it's definition the latest. problem solved.